# How do i update multiple records when i check a checkbox using php pdo?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlsrv

I am working on a project and  I want to assign a role to user by updating the table with values from checkbox. I want update multiple records using the checkbox. I want to update the newservice table when i select the users from the dropdown menu. I need help at this stage.

```
#assign estimator
      $gp = $userDetails->pgroup;
      $users = $db->prepare('SELECT
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].name AS fullname,
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].user_group AS pgroup,
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].username,
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].uid,
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].region,
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].district

      FROM dbo.[GWCL$west_users]
      WHERE
      dbo.[GWCL$west_users].user_group = 10
      ');
      $users->execute();



      #update and assign estimating officer

      if($_POST['process']){ 

          foreach($_POST['dm_approve'] as $id)
          {



               $update =$db->prepare('UPDATE dbo.[GWCL$NewServiceConnection] SET dbo.[GWCL$NewServiceConnection].staffID = '.$_POST['staffID'].',  dbo.[GWCL$NewServiceConnection].dm_approve = 1  WHERE dbo.[GWCL$NewServiceConnection].Application_ID ='.$id.'');
               $update->execute();
             $result = $update->rowCount();
      if ($result ===false) {
               echo "Failed";
               }else{
               echo "Status " .$id. " is assigned to ".$_POST['staffID'].". <br>";
              }

      } 
      }
      ?>
      <?php include('header.php'); ?>
      <body class="with-side-menu">

        <header class="site-header">
            <?php require_once('topnav.php');?>
           <!--.container-fluid-->
        </header><!--.site-header-->

        <div class="mobile-menu-left-overlay"></div>
        <?php require_once('nav.php');?>
          <!--.side-menu-->

        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <header class="section-header">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <div class="tbl-row">
                            <div class="tbl-cell">
                                <h2>NSC Applications Pending Estimation </h2>
                                <div class="subtitle"><?php #echo $aName['Name'];?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header><?php   if(isset($_GET['msg']))
          {
              $Message = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Successful!</strong> Estimation is made on Applicant's account
      </div>";
              echo $Message;
          }?>
                <section class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                      <div class="col-sm-4"><form name="nmc" id="wrapped" method="POST" action="assignedcust.php">
                               </div> <div class="col-sm-4"><select name="staffID" autofocus class="form-control" id="staffID" >
                                <option value=""  selected>Select Estimator</option>
                              <?php foreach($users as $user){?>

                                <option value="<?php echo $user['username'];?>" ><?php echo $user['fullname'];?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                              </select></div> <input type="submit" name="process" id="submit" value="Assign"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
                        <table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes" label="check all"  align="left"/> Select All                                   
                                                                                                                                </th>
                                <th>Applicant Name </th>
                                <th>Activity</th>
                                <th>Mobile</th>
                                <th>Service Type</th>
                                <th>Purpose</th>
                                <th>House Number</th>
                                  <th>Estimate</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($asscust as $acust){?><tr>
                              <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="dm_approve[]" id="dm_approve[]" value="<?php echo $acust['Application_ID']; ?>">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="dm_approve[]" id="dm_approve[]"  value="<?php echo $acust['Application_ID']; ?>" class="chk_boxes1"><?php echo $acust['Application_ID']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><?php echo $acust['Applicant_Name'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $acust['Activity'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $acust['Mobile_No'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $acust['Service_Category'];?></td>
                                <td><?php  echo $acust['Purpos_Supply'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $acust['House_No'];?></td>
                                  <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="estimater.php?ID=<?php echo $acust['Application_ID'];?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Estimate</a> | <a class="btn btn-default" href="assignesti.php?ID=<?php echo $acust['Application_ID'];?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Assign</a>                                                       </td>
                            </tr><?php }?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table></form>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, if you need me to explain it just leave a comment. It simply checks all the checked inputs when btn pressed and after this it makes an ajax request and It updates values in your db. I did it so if u checked for exmaple the fourth input it will not update it again untill u refresh tha page.

```
`<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var arr=[];

function send()
{
var neww=[];
  //get all of the  inputs that are checked
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function (input){


  if ($(this).is(":checked")==true)
  {
    if (arr.indexOf($(this).attr('value'))<0)
    {
      arr.push($(this).attr('value'));
      neww.push($(this).attr('value'));
    }
  }


})
var string = JSON.stringify(neww);
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"up.php",
dataType:"json",
data:{"values": string},
success: function (res)
{
  //do what u want when this complete
}
})
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="1">1</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="2">2</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="3">3</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="check4" value="4">4</input><br>

<input type="button" onclick="send()" value="Click me"></input>

</body>
</html>
`
```

And The up.php is here :

```
    <?php
$yes =  array();
$string=json_decode($_GET["values"]);

//db connect
$con = new mysqli("localhost","yourusername","yourpass","yourdb");

foreach ($string as $val) {

$sql="INSERT INTO yourtabel Values ('',{$val})";
$con->query($sql);
}
//echo json_encode("bv");
?>
```